# how to enable an intent in dialogflow?

Tags: android-intent, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I created my first intent in dialogflow, but i don't know how to enable it so I can test it.

every time I typed something in the test control, the intent it shows is 'default welcome intent', and so I deleted that intent, but my problem still stands.